# How do I add min and max values to a mean plot (sciplot)

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to simultaneously plot the mean, min, max and the 95% confidence intervals (CI) for a given data:

`duration <- sample(1:100, 12, replace=F)`

```
locality <- c(rep("loc1", 6), rep("loc2", 6))

data <- data.frame(locality, duration)
```

I've already managed to plot them separately, but could not figure a way to blend those informations so that the error bars represent the 95% CI, and the min and max values are displayed as points below and above the error bars.

[plot using 95% confidence intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMOq0.jpg)

```
library(sciplot)
lineplot.CI(data$locality, data$duration, type="p",
        ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm=T)-qt(0.975, nrow(data)-2)*se(x, na.rm=T), 
                              mean(x, na.rm=T)+qt(0.975, nrow(data)-2)*se(x, na.rm=T)))
```

[plot using min and max values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wrwG.jpg)

```
   lineplot.CI(data$locality, data$duration, type="p",
        ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)-min(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                              mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)+max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I've looked into the R's help and searched for possible solutions on the internet, but could not figure a way to do it.

Comment: Add a dataset and modify your code to illustrate the problem you are having.

Comment: I've edited the code and added a random dataset to illustrate it better

Comment: I just looked at the code for lineplot.CI and as far as I can see it's all base graphics, so it shouldn't be hard to add a `points` call to add `min`s and `max`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I outlined in my comment. The x-values for plotting are just ascending integers, probably derived from factor-values for `data$locality` although I haven't dived into the code to confirm that:

```
 png();res <- 
 lineplot.CI( data$locality, data$duration, type="p",
         ci.fun= function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm=T)-qt(0.975, nrow(data)-2)*se(x, na.rm=T), 
                               mean(x, na.rm=T)+qt(0.975, nrow(data)-2)*se(x, na.rm=T)) , ylim= c( min(data$duration), max(data$duration) ))
 points( rep(1,2) , c( min(data$duration[ data$locality=="loc1"]), 
                       max(data$duration[data$locality=="loc1"]) ) )
 points( rep(2,2) , c( min(data$duration[ data$locality=="loc2"]), 
                       max(data$duration[data$locality=="loc2"]) ) )
 dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! I've managed to create graphs using the actual data. Cheers!

However, I ended up with a huge scrip. Any thoughts on how it could be embedded within the lineplot.ci function?

Comment: You could loop over the labels for x after the initial lineplot.CI call. Would that make the code footprint acceptably smaller? (It would of course be possible to hack a new function that had options for automatic annotations, but that might be another question.)